# XML createElement double quotes DocumentBuilder api

Tags: java, xml, quotes, double-quotes

I would like to create an XML file by a java program.
XML Structure is the following

```
<PERSON transactionType="ADD">
   <AGE>30</AGE>
<PERSON>
```

The problem is that I cannot add double quotes in the first element (PERSON) as it is needed for my SOAP request.
I tried many solutions found but nothing worked.

Example code:

```
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("transactionType=\"ADD"\";);
```

Comment: The element is `PERSON`. The `transactionType` is an _attribute_ you add to the element. Then when you export it to text, it should have the double quotes automatically.

Comment: I think you need something like `Element person = doc.getDocumentElement(); person.setAttribute("transactionType", "ADD");`. Because transactionType is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `transationType` as an attribute.

```
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("PERSON");
Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("transactionType");
attr.setValue("ADD");
rootElement.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

Note: it will be double-quoted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element root =
    element("PERSON")
        .attribute("transactionType", "ADD")
        .child(element("AGE").text("30"));
System.out.println(simple.domToXml(root));
```

Will output:

```
<PERSON transactionType="ADD"><AGE>30</AGE></PERSON>
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```